# CakePHP: validation of associations without database

Tags: cakephp-2.4

How can i create and validate associated models without database tables?

I want to use the models to collect user input and validate it. I would like to make use of the built in model validation of associated models without having a database.

Answer (score 0):

Specify in your Models that you don't need the database table :

```
class MyModel extends AppModel {
    public $useTable = false;
}
```

The rest of the validation and associations should be configured in the same way as if you were using the DB.

For further informations, see the doc : http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/model-attributes.html

Comment: Hi, thanks, I knew that. But what do i do with the associations? I have some model, that is assiciated to several other models. All these models contain user data, that should be validated, when i call the "validates" function on the first model.

Comment: Bad Return Key...



At the moment, I have one table per model. But I have to get rid of these tables for some reason and save all the data in a json sturcture as a string. So basically I want to change as few as possible in my model classes, when I change the database.

Answer (score 0):

Add this (be sure to have the $validate array in YourModel):

```
public $useTable = false;
```

and validate in YourController with this:

```
if($this->YourModel->validates()) {
    // No Validation Errors
}
```

and checkout the documentation: http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/data-validation/validating-data-from-the-controller.html